# Angular 4 file upload with other post data giving empty object on server side (node js)

Tags: node.js, angular, file, express

I am stuck with a problem from last 3 hours, I was trying to upload file and other post data to the server side, I am using angular for frontend part and node for server side. 
This is my `component.ts` code

```js
save(data) {
    console.log(data);
    const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
    console.log(files);
    for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        this.formData.append("image[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
    }

    //trying to send some dummy entry but no luck
    this.formData.append('title','dasdasdas');
    // console.log(this.formData.getAll('image'));
    // console.log('form data variable :   '+ 
    this.formData.toString());
    // console.log(this.formData.getAll('image[]'));
    this.restApi.addRecipe(this.formData).subscribe(res => 
        {
            console.log(res);
        });
```

This is my angular service code:

```
addRecipe(data){
    console.log(this.baseUrl);
    const headers = new Headers({});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'addRecipe',data,options).map(res=>res.json());
}
```

This is my `server.js` code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const admin = require('./routes/admin');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const config = require('./config/config');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(config.database, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('connected')
    }
})

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')));
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
//admin route
app.use('/admin', admin);

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log("err");
       console.log("port started");
    })
```

This is the controller code where I have written the logic of inserting:

```
module.exports.addRecipe = (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body
    console.log(body);
    return;
    ...
}
```

whenever I `console.log(body)`, I am getting a empty object {}, from the angular side I have tried changing the content type but nothing seems to be working, I am new to node and angular and I searched a lot about this problem but no solution seems to be working.